# How to handle an array of input arguments when embedding python in .net

Tags: python, .net, python.net

Given the following example:

```
    public void execute(object[] inputs, object output)
    {
        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            dynamic np = Py.Import("programs.test_program");

            output = np.func(?????);
        }
    }
```

The question is how can I put my array of arguments in `np.func`. In python we can do packed positional argument `*[]` how can I implement that here?

Comment: On Python side you can make a wrapper function that accepts function and arguments as input and import/use it from C#: `def wrapstarcall(func,args): return func(*args)`

Comment: what is the `func` and `args` I should pass to in my c# code

Comment: `func` is your `np.func`, `args` is your ?????